# Changing <div> Background on Check Box check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I posted a similar question yesterday, but this is new problem.

I have dynamically created Check Boxes on a page. On is the Parent Check Box and the rest are the child check boxes. Each Child Check Box is wrapped in a `<div>`. I have a drop down list. When I select an item from the list, the Check Boxes gets checked or unchecked. When the check box state changes, the `<div>` in witch it is wrapped background colour changes or when I check or uncheck it.

My problem. When I check/uncheck the parent check box it also checks/unchecks the child ones, but the background colour of the child check boxes' `<div>` does not change.

I need it to still work as it is currently working but also to have the new feature as required.

**My Code:**

**1. CSS:**

```
<style>

div.sch_cal_row {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: white;
    height: 20px;
}


div.highlight {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #78EF5A;
    /*background-color: #E0FBD9;*/
    /*background-color: green;*/
}
div.high1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #F24F40;
    /*background-color: #FFA07A;*/
    /*background-color: red;*/
}

div.available {
    width: 100px;
    height: 46px;
    background-color: #A8A69C;
}
</style>
```

**2. JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".childChk").each(function(){
    check($(this));
});
$(".childChk").click(function () {
    check($(this));
});

function check(chkElem) {
    if (chkElem.is(':checked')) {
        chkElem.parent().removeClass();
        chkElem.parent().addClass("highlight");
    } else {
        chkElem.parent().removeClass("highlight");
        chkElem.parent().addClass("high1");
    }
}
</script>
```

**3. HTML/Razor:**

```
<div id="Priv">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Categories[i].AllChecked, new { id = Model.Categories[i].CategoryID, @class = "parentChk" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Categories[i].CategoryName)
        <strong>@Model.Categories[i].CategoryName</strong>
        <br />
        @*@Html.JTDisplayTextFor(m => Model.Categories[i].CategoryName, "")*@
        @for (var p = 0; p < Model.Categories[i].Privileges.Count; p++)
        {
            <div class="sch_cal_row">
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Categories[i].Privileges[p].PrivilegeID)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Categories[i].Privileges[p].PrivilegeName)
                 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Categories[i].Privileges[p].Checked, new { @class = "childChk" })
                 @Html.JTDisplayTextFor(m => Model.Categories[i].Privileges[p].PrivilegeName, "")
            </div>

         }
        <br />
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

**UPDATE as per comment:**

```
<input class="parentChk" data-val="true" data-val-required="The AllChecked field is required." id="4" name="Categories[0].AllChecked" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Categories[0].AllChecked" type="hidden" value="false">
<input id="Categories_0__CategoryName" name="Categories[0].CategoryName" type="hidden" value="Account">
<strong>Account</strong>
<br>
    <div class="sch_cal_row high1">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PrivilegeID must be a number." data-val-required="The PrivilegeID field is required." id="Categories_0__Privileges_0__PrivilegeID" name="Categories[0].Privileges[0].PrivilegeID" type="hidden" value="8">
        <input id="Categories_0__Privileges_0__PrivilegeName" name="Categories[0].Privileges[0].PrivilegeName" type="hidden" value="AccountAddEdit">
        <input class="childChk" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Checked field is required." id="Categories_0__Privileges_0__Checked" name="Categories[0].Privileges[0].Checked" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Categories[0].Privileges[0].Checked" type="hidden" value="false">
    &nbsp;AccountAddEdit<br>
    </div>
```

This is only the parent and one child.

Comment: show us generated html

Answer (score 0):

You right your javascript code in document.ready

```
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
       $(".childChk").each(function(){
         check($(this));
       });
       $(".childChk").click(function () {
         check($(this));
       });
    });
   function check(chkElem) {
     if (chkElem.is(':checked')) {
       chkElem.parent().removeClass();
       chkElem.parent().addClass("highlight");
     } else {
       chkElem.parent().removeClass("highlight");
       chkElem.parent().addClass("high1");
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
$('.childChk').on("click", function(){
        var thisParent = $(this).parent();
        if(thisParent.hasClass("highlight")) {
           thisParent.removeClass("highlight")
        } else {
           thisParent.addClass("highlight")
        }                
    });
```